# How do you require a parameter to be a class implementing an interface?

Tags: java, android, methods, interface

I know that you can require children of a class in methods

i.e.

```
method(Class<? extends Object> var)
```

But I need the method to receive a parameter implementing a certain interface, actually two interfaces

i.e.

```
method(Class<? implements Interface, Interface2> var)
```

Is this possible in Android/Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an instance of an interface this requires the object in question to be a "child".  This should do what you want

```
method(NameOfInterface1 var1, NameOfInterface2 var2){ stuff...}
```

For example suppose I have an interface "Person" and a class "Bob" that implements "Person".  Then

```
method(Person var1, Person var2) { stuff... }
```

This method will accept all classes that implement Person, including Bob.

Edit.

Given that you want the method to accept a parameter that implements two interfaces, you can create a third interface such that

```
interface Interface3 extends Interface1, Interface2
```

and then create children that implement Interface3

Comment: `interface Interface3 extends Interface1, Interface2` Is this Interface3 alright to be used as a type to a parameter?

Comment: In Java/Android you cannot create an instance of an interface, ie by calling new Interface3().  You can however do the following Interface3 i = new ClassImplementingInterfac3();.  You could then pass i as a parameter to a method that accepts objects of type Interface3.  So the tldr is yes, you can.  But the object that is ultimately passed to the method must be of a type that implements the interface (in this case Interface3).